# How do I reorder and combine sublists based on sublist rankings given by another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have two lists:

```
list = {{5, 6, 10}, {6}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8}, {6, 4}, {9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 
   10}, {4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {3}, {8, 10, 8}, {9, 10}, {9, 10, 7, 7}}

sublistRank = {6, 5, 9, 6, 9, 5, 8, 6, 4, 8}
```

The values given in `sublistRank` are just arbitrary ranking values for each given sublist in `list`.  The position of each `sublistRank` value corresponds to the sublist (in `list`) in the same position.  For example, the first sublist of `{5, 6, 10}` has a ranking value of 6.  The second sublist has a ranking value of 5, the third sublist has a ranking value of 9, etc. What I'd like to do is the following:

First I want to reorder `sublistRank` to be in numerical order; this is easily given by `Sort[sublistRank]` which yields the output:

```
sortedsublistRank= {4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9}
```

I would then like to reorder `list` to be reflective of new ordering given to `sublistRank`.  I'm not sure how to go about this, but the output would look like:

```
{{9, 10}, {6}, {4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10}, {6, 4}, {8, 10, 
  8}, {3}, {9, 10, 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8}, {9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}
```

For this step, the specific ordering of sublists which have the same rank do not matter.  For example, the 2nd and 3rd sublists have a ranking value of 5, but it does not matter which sublist comes first, they'd be interchangeable.

Once I have the newly sorted `list` I'd then like to combine all sublists which have the same rank.  This would yield the final desired output of:

```
{{9,10},{6,4,6,6,5,7},{5,6,10,6,4,8,10,8},{3,9,10,7,7},{5,9,4,8,8,9,4,5,2,10,8,10}}
```

Any advice on how to go about implementing either of the two steps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Combine them together

```
Transpose[{sublistRank, list}] // GatherBy[#, First] &
```

```
{
    {{6, {5, 6, 10}}, {6, {6, 4}}, {6, {8, 10, 8}}},
    {{5, {6}}, {5, {4, 6, 6, 5, 7}}},
    {{9, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8}}, {9, {9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}},
    {{8, {3}}, {8, {9, 10, 7, 7}}},
    {{4, {9, 10}}}
    }
```

then write a function to deal with data

```
f[x_] := {x // First // First, Last /@ x // Flatten}
```

```
{
            {{6, {5, 6, 10}}, {6, {6, 4}}, {6, {8, 10, 8}}},
            {{5, {6}}, {5, {4, 6, 6, 5, 7}}},
            {{9, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8}}, {9, {9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}},
            {{8, {3}}, {8, {9, 10, 7, 7}}},
            {{4, {9, 10}}}
            } // Map[f] // SortBy[#, First] &
```

Now we get

```
{{4, {9, 10}}, {5, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}}, {6, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 
            8}}, {8, {3, 9, 10, 7, 7}}, {9, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 
            10}}}
```

Take the last item of each item

```
{{4, {9, 10}}, {5, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}}, {6, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 
                8}}, {8, {3, 9, 10, 7, 7}}, {9, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8,
                    10}}} // Map[Last]
```

We get

```
{{9, 10}, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8}, {3, 9, 10, 
        7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) + [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to get `list` sorted by `sublistRank` (your first list):

```
orderedlist = list[[Ordering @ sublistRank]]
```

> ```
> {{9, 10}, {6}, {4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10}, {6, 4}, {8, 10, 8}, {3},
>  {9, 10, 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8}, {9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}
> ```

and for your final list:

```
Values @ GroupBy[Thread[{orderedlist, Sort @ sublistRank}], Last -> First, Flatten]
```

> {{9, 10}, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8},
> {3, 9, 10, 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}

Alternatively, construct associations from `sublistRank` and `list` and use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html):

```
assocs = Association /@ Thread[sublistRank -> list];

Catenate /@ Values @ KeySort @ Merge[Identity] @ assocs
```

> {{9, 10}, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8},
> {3, 9, 10, 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that hinges upon [PositionIndex](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html):

```
sublistRank // PositionIndex // KeySort // Values // Map[Catenate@list[[#]]&]

(* {{9, 10}, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8},
    {3, 9, 10, 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) [GroupByList](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GroupByList) to combine lists with common ranks in an association:

```
assoc = ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][list, sublistRank, Flatten]
```

> <|6 -> {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8}, 5 -> {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7},
> 9 -> {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}, 8 -> {3, 9, 10, 7, 7},
> 4 -> {9, 10}|>

Then, you can sort the keys and take the values:

```
Values @ KeySort @ assoc
```

> {{9, 10}, {6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7}, {5, 6, 10, 6, 4, 8, 10, 8}, {3, 9, 10,
> 7, 7}, {5, 9, 4, 8, 8, 9, 4, 5, 2, 10, 8, 10}}